# MySQL query consuming 5-6x normal CPU usage

Tags: mysql, optimization, query-optimization

When I run the query in phpMyAdmin it returns results within 0.3s at the most. Usually 0.19s ish is normal. It doesn't seem like the query is using much CPU but my hosting provider informs me that it's consuming quite a bit.

I'm wondering if the `UNION ALL` is the culprit for this or just the complexity of the query in general. Any insight would be appreciated.

Here's the query:

```
SELECT unitId, unitName, createDate
FROM (
    (SELECT game_player.unitId as unitId, unit.name as unitName, game.createDate as createDate
        FROM  `game_player` 
        LEFT JOIN `game` ON game_player.gameId = game.id
        LEFT JOIN `unit` ON game_player.unitId = unit.id
        WHERE game_player.playerId = 123
        AND game.createDate > 1390953600000
        AND game_player.unitId NOT IN (SELECT unitId FROM unit_free))

    UNION ALL

    (SELECT game_player.unitId as unitId, unit.name as unitName, game.createDate as createDate
        FROM  `game_player` 
        LEFT JOIN `game` ON game_player.gameId = game.id
        LEFT JOIN `unit` ON game_player.unitId = unit.id
        WHERE game_player.playerId = 123
        AND game.type = '5')
)
AS results
WHERE unitId NOT IN (SELECT unitId FROM player_units WHERE playerId = 123)
GROUP BY unitName
```

`game` is a list of games
`game_player` is a list of the players in a particular game
`unit` is a list of units that a player can use
`unit_free` is a list of free units that players can play
`player_units` is a list of known units that the player owns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly your 2 sub queries are very similar. They might both return the same rows (hence the union all), but you use GROUP_BY to eliminate one of the duplicates.

Your first sub query is checking a field from the game table (createDate) in the WHERE clause. For this to be true a match much have been found, hence an INNER JOIN could be used rather than a LEFT OUTER JOIN. Your second sub query does the same for the type field.

Lastly you are using `field IN (sub query)` type syntax which is poorly optimised in MySQL. A LEFT OUTER JOIN then checking for NULL will likely be faster.

Note that which value of unitName and createDate are returned for a final unitName is not defined. Might be any of them.

Ignoring this last point (if you can define which values you want I can attempt a further solution) then I would tweak the query as follows

```
SELECT unitId, unitName, createDate
FROM (
    (SELECT game_player.unitId as unitId, unit.name as unitName, game.createDate as createDate
        FROM  `game_player` 
        INNER JOIN `game` ON game_player.gameId = game.id AND game.createDate > 1390953600000
        LEFT OUTER JOIN `unit` ON game_player.unitId = unit.id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN unit_free ON game_player.unitId = unit_free.unitId
        LEFT OUTER JOIN player_units ON game_player.unitId = player_units.unitId AND playerId = game_player.playerId
        WHERE game_player.playerId = 123
        AND unit_free.unitId IS NULL
        AND player_units.unitId IS NULL)

    UNION ALL

    (SELECT game_player.unitId as unitId, unit.name as unitName, game.createDate as createDate
        FROM  `game_player` 
        INNER JOIN `game` ON game_player.gameId = game.id AND game.type = '5'
        LEFT OUTER JOIN `unit` ON game_player.unitId = unit.id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN player_units ON game_player.unitId = player_units.unitId AND playerId = game_player.playerId
        WHERE game_player.playerId = 123
        AND player_units.unitId IS NULL
        )
)
AS results
GROUP BY unitName
```

If a game_player unitId MUST appear in the unit table I would change those to inner joins as well.

Depending on the possible requirements of the value of createDate (ie, if more than one returned, which one to use) then it might well be possible to reduce this to either a single query, or a pair of unioned queries and remove the need for any sub queries.

EDIT

Following your comments, this can probably be simplified as:-

```
SELECT unit.id as unitId, unit.name as unitName, MAX(game.createDate) as createDate
FROM  `game_player` 
INNER JOIN `game` ON game_player.gameId = game.id 
INNER JOIN `unit` ON game_player.unitId = unit.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN unit_free ON game_player.unitId = unit_free.unitId
LEFT OUTER JOIN player_units ON game_player.unitId = player_units.unitId AND playerId = game_player.playerId
WHERE game_player.playerId = 123
AND ((unit_free.unitId IS NULL
AND game.createDate > 1390953600000) 
OR AND game.type = '5')
AND player_units.unitId IS NULL)
GROUP BY unitName, unitId
```

As game_player.unitId will always appear in unit.id we can use an INNER JOIN, and also rely using the id from the unit table directly (which will match the unit name - otherwise grouping by unit name could cause issues when 2 different units have the same name). As you just want a create date you can just use MAX() to get the latest one.

While it might be possible to get multiple rows returned due to unit_free the group by will remove these. As you are not summing up or counting the rows this shouldn't matter.

Assuming appropriate indexes this should be fairly fast.

Comment: Ahhh, the tip about `IN` being poorly optimized and using `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead is exactly the stuff I was looking for. And it doesn't matter what `unitName` and `createDate` is returned as long as one entry of ALL units that match the criteria is returned. And lastly, yes `game_player.unitId` will always appear in `unit.id`.

Comment: Oh also! Could you include a break down of CPU and time costs for different operations or link me to a site with this information. I'd like to know what CPU and time I'm sacrificing by making certain operations. THANKS!

Comment: Added a suggestion. Afraid I can't really help you with a break down of times, etc.

Comment: Damn, I look at my query and it's a mess. I really should have just taken the time to think through it like you've done. This tip about using `LEFT OUTER JOIN` in place of `IN` is really going to help me in the future, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Note that first of your inner subselects is perfect subset of another. With this in mind, why do you need `UNION ALL` in first place? Your query should be equivalent to this (except for removing possible duplicates):

```
SELECT unitId, unitName, createDate
FROM (
    SELECT game_player.unitId as unitId, unit.name as unitName, game.createDate as createDate
    FROM  `game_player` 
    LEFT JOIN `game` ON game_player.gameId = game.id
    LEFT JOIN `unit` ON game_player.unitId = unit.id
    WHERE game_player.playerId = 123
) AS results
WHERE unitId NOT IN (SELECT unitId FROM player_units WHERE playerId = 123)
GROUP BY unitName
```

Then, when you `GROUP BY unitName`, you should use some aggregate function on other fields in your outer `SELECT`, like `sum()`, `count()`, `avg()` or similar - otherwise it makes no sense at all.

After you fix these issues, run your query wrapped in `EXPLAIN ANALYZE VERBOSE`, and make sure that query is using indexes. If it is using sequential scan or filesort, make sure to add missing indexes, most likely multi-column ones.

Comment: Ah you're right, I fixed it. The 2nd subselect actually has a 2nd condition AND game.type = '5' so the first query gathers games where the player didn't use a free unit and the second query gathers games where the player played game type '5'.